# usb wifi adapter not work on lubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, lubuntu

I have a usb wifi adapter that works perfectly on my computer with other distros but it doesn't work on lubuntu 22.04.1. I installed the driver following the instructions from this link: https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
The driver installs, but NetworkManager does not find any wifi networks. I tried installing both ways, compiling the source code from github and using ppa, neither worked.
I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: It doesn't need to '*find*' networks, you just enter the details of your wifi network as provided in the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.4/nm-tray.html) and then connect... if the details (name/key etc) are correct you'll be connected.

Comment: I've tried this before, no connection has been established. When I click on "Wi -Fi - request scan" nothing is found.

Comment: Don't scan; just enter the details (SSID, Device (*from drop down*), Wi-Fi security method & password) using *Edit Connections*..   Most networks I connect to are hidden, so requesting scan won't find them anyway (*until the details are entered that first time*)

Comment: The network I trying connect is not hidden. Also I tried to connect by typing the details of the connection manually and did not work.